# Primes not dividing sequence $a_{n+1} = 1 + a_0 a_1 \cdots a_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

> Prove that there are infinitely many primes that divide none of the elements of the integer sequence
> $a_{n+1} =1+a_0 a_1 \cdots a_n$, with a starting point of $a_0 \geq 0$.

I thought about $$\log (x_n-1)=\log x_0x_1\cdots x_{n-1}= \log x_0 + \log x_1 +\cdots+\log x_{n-1} $$ to solve the problem but couldn't.

Comment: This question should be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Asked there nobody helped asked here you didn't help

Comment: Maybe you should have tried improving the question on math.SE according to the comments instead of asking it on another SE community…

Comment: Often problems like these are best by contradiction. Disclaimer: I haven't tried this problem myself yet, but my approach would be to assume there were finitely many primes that divide none of those elements, then there is a largest prime with that property, then I would try to find a larger one.

Comment: Seems easy if you don't look hard enough, but then it suddenly gets a lot harder. For a0 = 1, the sequence starts with 1, 2, 3, 7, 43, 1807, 1 + 1806*1807, and so on. The numbers grow rapidly (number of digits doubles every time), so the usual method "calculate a few values and see what happens" doesn't work.

Comment: I also just want to weigh in and say I think this question is appropriate for computer science.

Comment: If the first element is zero, this is easy... (assuming no prime divides zero)

Comment: Observe that $4a_{n+2}=(2a_n+1)^2+3$. So, for an odd prime $p$ to divide $a_{n+2}$ it must be the case that $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. By [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B13) $p$ would have to be a quadratic residue modulo $3$. This is, leave remainder $1$ (or $0$) modulo $3$. So, any odd prime that leaves remainder $2$ after division by $3$ cannot divide $4a_{n+2}$ and in particular $a_{n+2}$. There are infinitely many primes of the form $3k+2$. See, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627789).

Comment: Are you yourself deleting all your questions or are they getting deleted by other users? The answers that you got can be useful to others.

Comment: There is a typo in my first comment. Where it says $a_n$ it should say $a_0a_1\dotsm a_n$. The rest stays the same.

Comment: Plop, you should make that an answer. And you’re too quick for me :-) I assumed a_0 =1, and defined b_k = product a_0 to a_k. b_k mod 5 goes in a cycle. b_k modulo 11 goes in a cycle. b_k mod anything goes in a cycle or becomes 0. Next step (didn’t get there) would have been to see for which primes b_k goes in a cycle, and for which ones it ends in 0.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, remainders of recurrences of order $k$ always fall into a cycle because there are only finitely many $k$-tuples of remainders that the previous $k$ terms can have. In your case $$\begin{align}a_{n+1}&=b_n+1\\b_{n+1}&=a_{n+1}b_n\end{align}$$ is a $2$-dimensional recurrence of order $1$, or $b_{n+1}=(b_n+1)b_n$ also of order $1$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in [math.se].

Answer (score 3):

Let me write it here, because I had a typo in the comment.

First observe that
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+2}&=1+a_0a_1\dotsm a_na_{n+1}\\
&=1+a_0a_1\dotsm a_n(1+a_0a_1\dotsm a_n)
\end{align}$$

So $$4a_{n+2}=(2a_0a_1\dotsm a_n+1)^2+3$$

This implies that for an odd prime $p$ that divides $a_{n+2}$, we must have that $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. By [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B13), $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, when $p$ itself is a quadratic residue modulo $3$. Therefore, any odd prime of the form $3K+2$, with $K\in\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have $-3$ as quadratic residue and  cannot divide $4a_{n+2}$ for any $n\geq0$.

Since there are infinitely many primes of the form $3K+2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627789) for example), then an infinite collection of primes that don't divide any of the elements of the sequence are the primes of the form $3K+2$, excluding from them $2$, the primes that divide $a_0$ and the primes that divide $a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a_1 \cdots a_m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for some prime $p$, which in particular implies that $p$ doesn't divide $a_1,\ldots,a_m$. We claim that $a_i \equiv a_{i \bmod m} \pmod{p}$ for $i > 0$, where the modulo returns an answer in the range $1,\ldots,m$. We prove this by induction. This is clear when $i \leq m$. Now suppose it holds for all $j < i$. Let $i-1 = dm + r$, where $0 \leq r < m$. Then modulo $p$,
\begin{align}
a_i &= 1 + a_0 \cdots a_{i-1} \\ &\equiv
1 + a_0 (a_1 \cdots a_m)^d a_1 \cdots a_r \\ &\equiv
1 + a_0 a_1 \cdots a_r \\ &=a_{r+1}.
\end{align}

It follows that if $p$ doesn't divide $a_0$, then it doesn't divide any element in the sequence.

It thus suffices to show that there are infinitely many primes that occur as factors of $a_1 \cdots a_m - 1$ (only finitely many can divide $a_0$).

---

Let us now assume that $a_0 = 1$, and so $a_1 = 2$. If $p$ is any prime divisor of $a_1 \cdots a_m - 1$ then $a_1 \cdots a_{km+1} \equiv a_1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, since no prime can divide $a_1 - 1 = 1$.

In particular, this implies that a prime divisor of $a_1 \cdots a_{a_j} - 1$ cannot be a prime divisor of $a_1 \cdots a_{a_{j+1}} - 1$. It follows that there are infinitely many primes that occur as factors of $a_1 \cdots a_m - 1$.

I'm not quite sure how to handle larger $a_0$ at the moment.

Comment: I think it can be finished the following way: Assume that $a_0=P^B$, where $P^B$ is a shorthand for a product of some primes to some positive exponents. Now, if $a_1a_2\dotsm a_m-1$ is divisible by primes not in $P$ we are in business. So, assume that $a_1\dotsm a_m-1=P^C$, with $C$ some tuple of non-negative exponents. We have that $a_1\dotsm a_{m+1}-1=a_1\dotsm a_m(a_0a_1\dotsm a_m+1)-1=(P^C+1)(P^B(P^C+1)+1)-1=P^{2C+B}+2P^{B+C}+P^B+P^C$. Now, let $q$ be a prime in $P$ and $b>0,c\geq0$ its exponents in $B,C$, respectively. We can factor out $q^{\min(b,c)}$, but ...

Comment: ... the remaining factor is a multiple of $q$ plus either $1$ or $2$, depending on the case. The possibility of $q$ being $2$ needs to be studied separately but one can see an odd factor remaining. So, we can always find a $a_1\dotsm a_m-1$ that is divisible by some prime, that doesn't divide $a_1-1=a_0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that $x^2+x+1$ doesn't have any prime divisor of the form $3n-1$ and
$x_{n+1}=1+x_0x_1...x_n$ so $x_{n+1} = 1 +A$ then $x_{n+2} = A^2+A+1$ and we are done because there are infinitely many $3n-1$ primes